# Hiding a template/imported node using JQuery - hide() not working

Tags: jquery

I am using a template to prepend to a container, and it is working properly, except that I would like the element to fade in. When I use the hide() function however, the element is still visible.

```
$('.newQuestion').on('click', function() {
    var template = document.querySelector('#newQuestion');
    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    $('.questionsList').prepend(clone);
    $(clone).hide(); //not hidden
    // $(clone).fadeIn(); <-- want to do this but needs to be hidden first
  });
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1q1o4cao/3/ click on the button, and the template is added, but not hidden.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I belive the problem is, that you pass the wrong type to jQuery. You have to select the added element in jQuery first. I think `$(clone)` does not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value of the `importNode` is a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). You are appending (moving) the elements of the DocumentFragment to another element. Now the fragment is empty and calling `hide` has no effect.

One option is creating a collection by using `.childNodes` property of the `DocumentFragment` and then calling the `.hide()` method:

```
$('.newQuestion').on('click', function() {
  var template = document.querySelector('#newQuestion');
  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  $(clone.childNodes).hide().appendTo('.questionsList').fadeIn(); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ty146t5o/

Comment: thank you for the explanation of why that was happening in addition to a solution, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you do this

```
$(".questionsList div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv2q9jvj/1/

What you need to do is select the node with a Jquery selector:

```
var $newQ = $('.questionsList div:first');
```

Using :first selects the first child element, which holds your new question. Then you can hide it and fade in:

```
$newQ.hide();
$newQ.fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example. Less code, same effect.
https://jsfiddle.net/1q1o4cao/7/

```
$('.newQuestion').on('click', function() {
    $('.questionsList').prepend($("#newQuestion").html());
    $('.questionsList div:first-child').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

Even possible in one single line, if you like it flat.
https://jsfiddle.net/1q1o4cao/8/

```
$('.questionsList').prepend($("#newQuestion").html()).find("div:first-child").hide().fadeIn();
```